# Applying a filter on XML elements based on attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, filter

Hi I need help please to apply a filter on my XML file that allows to get these results.I want to obtain only the blocs  with  type= NET in the output.

this is the original input:

```
<liv dt="2015-10-22" ><Qty type ="NET"> 55</Qty> </liv>
<liv dt="2015-11-1" ><Qty type ="FAR"> 558</Qty> </liv>
<liv dt="2015-10-2" ><Qty type ="NET"> 444</Qty> </liv>
<liv dt="2015-10-28" ><Qty type ="MAE"> 1222</Qty> </liv>
```

the Ouput required :

```
<liv dt="2015-10-22" ><Qty type ="NET"> 55</Qty> </liv>
<liv dt="2015-10-2" ><Qty type ="NET"> 444</Qty> </liv>
```

I tried to apply :

```
    <xsl:template match="/liv/Qty[not(@Typ='NET')"/>
```

this eliminate only the qty I want to remove all the bloc liv when this condition is satisfied, could you helpe please?

Thanks

Comment: Try `liv[Qty[not(@type='NET')]]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried it it seems that it doen't provide the required output.

Comment: If you're capable of mistyping "type" as "Typ" then heaven only knows what other mistakes are present in your code. But the next one is that if you have more than one `liv` element in your document, then it can't be the root element, and therefore `/liv` won't match it.

Comment: yeah actually I'm using Typ, liv is not the root element,it is company.that is the code that I'm using : <xsl:template  match="/company/liv[/company/liv/Qty[not(@Typ='NET')]]"/>

Comment: finally it works it should be like this : <xsl:template match="/company/liv[Qty[not(@Typ='NET')]]"/>. Thanks a lot for the Help :))

Comment: Note that you can just do `<xsl:template match="liv[Qty[not(@Typ='NET')]]"/>` here. You don't need the full path to the `liv` element specified in this case. (You would only really need it if you had `liv` elements at other levels in your XML that you didn't want matched).